# sharepoint search doesn't work properly after change environment

Tags: xslt, search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a trouble in sharepoint search.
I have dev environment and customize the Core search web part results.
The results view changed with xlst. In xslt i use HitHighlighting template for highlighting search results and jquery for replacing # symbols.
On dev environment search site work great, but when I moved my settings to test environment some functionality doesn't work.
Search works with title in query, with query includes title and some properties, but doesn't work with query includes title with some other properties.
I tried to output search raw result and all of searched properties are in raw result. But when I use query like title and one of "problem" property the raw result return empty.

Why sharepoint search returns no result on query with "problem" property and return this property in raw result with title search query.
Where can be the difference in my environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem.
At test environment I delete Search service with database from services in CA.
Then I create a new one and configured it. Search start works properly.